# activemq NoB: broker not getting messages after reconnect

Tags: activemq-classic, broker, subscriber

We have a hub-and-spoke network topology with activemq with topic and durable subscribers.

After a (embedded) broker has been disconnected, it does not get the messages that have been sent during the disconnection period while it does send its local pending messages.

Example:
broker A (embedded) <---> central broker (standalone) <---> broker B (embedded)

After broker A has been disconnect for more than 30s (max innactivity timeout for openwire), it does not get from the central broker the messages that have been sent while disconnect. However, broker A sends all its pending messages so broker B receives all of them.

Central broker does not have a specific network connector defined, since it is not known before hand which brokers has to connect to.

Tried with several recovery policies, but none seems to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are various issues with durable topics and clustered brokers...

if possible, try using [virtual topics](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) instead.  they are simple to setup, behave like persistent queues and seem to be much more reliable...